# Late variable in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, websocket

I'm new to use Websocket in Flutter.

So I was reading some post (https://blog.logrocket.com/using-websockets-flutter/) to understand how to use websocket, and I have some question.

The guy in this post declare _etheWebsocket,_btcWebsocket variables as late as below.

```
class CoinbaseProvider {
  late final WebSocketChannel _ethWebsocket;
  late final WebSocketChannel _btcWebsocket;

  CoinbaseProvider()
      : _ethWebsocket = WebSocketChannel.connect(
          Uri.parse('wss://ws-feed.pro.coinbase.com'),
        ),
        _btcWebsocket = WebSocketChannel.connect(
          Uri.parse('wss://ws-feed.pro.coinbase.com'),
        );
```

But why not just declare without late like below??
What is the reason have to declare WebsocketChannel as late.

```
class CoinbaseProvider {
  final WebSocketChannel _ethWebsocket = WebSocketChannel.connect(
    Uri.parse('wss://ws-feed.pro.coinbase.com'),
  );
  final WebSocketChannel _btcWebsocket = WebSocketChannel.connect(
    Uri.parse('wss://ws-feed.pro.coinbase.com'),
  );

  CoinbaseProvider();
```

Comment: late to field means that the field will be initialized when you use it for the first time.

Comment: Your question is more related to the usage of late variable in Dart rather than "How to use websocket in Flutter", you can improve your question by editing your title

Comment: @GHPrakash . Anywhy once I declare CoinProvider class, both cases make WebSocketChannel. Then why it has to be late variable?

Answer (score 2):

### Short explanation

You declaration looks better, since in your context you have the values to the variables `_ethWebsocket` and `_btcWebsocket`

### But why? a dive into `late` and null-safety features

[What's null-safety in Dart?](https://dart.dev/null-safety) This is a recent released feature (2021) that in summary it prevent us, developers, to create variables of a type that can be implicity `null`, then avoiding runtime errors as `TypeError: can't read property '...' of null`

But in summary, unlike before null-safety, now:

> All variables can't be `null` **implicity** by default!

#### Show me the code

- **Before null-safety:**

This snippet below is a valid statement before null-safety, this variable can be a String `'hi!'` or `null`

```dart
String myVariable; // null by default
```

- **After null-safety:**

The same snippet now is a invalid statement, the variable should be initialized because her can't be `null`

```
String myVariable; // Error!
```

To declare a variable that can be null by default, as like before the null-safety update you should write as:

```dart
String? myVariable; // Note the '?' after the Type
```

- **But what if you want to declare variable without the value and without explicitly declaring that it can be null?**

> The answer is `late`!

`late` is just a Dart language feature to allow you say to the compiler: "Hey, I don't have the value of this variable right now, but I promise you I'll set her somewhere else before using it, so her can't be null"

```
late String myVariable;

print(myVariable); // Throws an LateInitializationError instead of printing 'null'
```

### Conclusion

Given these features and the null-safety use them to avoid wasting time with null pointer exceptions and improve your code typing.

So there's no right or better way, all depends on the context.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Yeah I understood about late variable. So what is difference btw 2 cases which I wrote (CoinbaseProvider class). Without late variable also can work, But what is different if i use late?

Comment: perfect explanation for beginners!!!

Answer (score 0):

For the exact example you used I would say they are identical, and your version would be better. My guess it that they made it like that, is to allow adding additional constructors, maybe like

```
CoinbaseProvider.customUrl(String eth, String btc)
  : _ethWebsocket = WebSocketChannel.connect(
      Uri.parse(eth),
    ),
    _btcWebsocket = WebSocketChannel.connect(
      Uri.parse(btc),
    );
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Then... If CoinbaseProvider doesn't need to allow additional constructors, it is okay to declare without late variable.... is my understanding correct??